# Best practice to create a .NET configuration file editor application?

Tags: config

I've to develop a small WPF  (.NET fwk 4.5) app which will allow the user to edit the appSettings section of 5 files differents .config file.

These 5 files are application configuration file of 4 console applications and 1 WPF composite application.

In each file, the appsettings will hold SMTP/POP3 server addresses,  configuration  and other misc. information.

My question :  are some best Microsoft best practices available to create this kind of app?

is there a way to downsize/factorize my 5 files into a single one or at least create a xml formatted file holding common appSetting for the 5 app to configure?

Thanks for your reply,

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found it myself : factorize using the file attribute of the appSettings element; here what I've done :

```
<appSettings file="..\appSettings.config"></appSettings>
```

Use XPath query and XMLDocument class of .NET framework :

```
XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDocument.Load('appSettings.config');
XmlNode root = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/appSettings");
string attributeName = "smtpServer";
XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("/appSettings/add[@key='" + attributeName + "']");
//read value of 'value attribute' of node
var myValue = node.Attributes["value"].Value; 
myXmlDocument.Save("appSettings.config");
```